# The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

The application will run fine unless I add the following code.

```
public class TFView extends View{
  private Paint p;
  private ArrayList<Orb> O1;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public TFView (Context context){
    super(context);
    O1=new ArrayList<Orb>();
    p = new Paint();
    int Orby=0; 
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
      int Orbx= 0;

      for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
      {
        O1.add(new Orb(Orbx,Orby,true));
        Orbx+= 40;
      }
      Orby+= 40;
    }
  }


  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    for(Orb t:O1){
      canvas.drawOval(t.drawOrb(), p);

    }
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(main.getx()), 50, 50, p);
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(main.gety()), 50, 80, p);
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(O1.size()), 50, 110, p);

    try {  
      Thread.sleep(30);  
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

    invalidate(); 
  }
}
```

So, I believe that my problem has something to do with the android not accepting my Arraylist. I have run a very similar code to this on my computer, but something about Android doesn't seem to want to accept it. Here is my Orb class that is used in my Arraylist.

```
import android.graphics.RectF;

public class Orb {
  static int orbx;
  static int orby;
  public int size;
  static RectF button;

  boolean display;
  public Orb(){
    orbx=0;
    orby=0;
    display=false;
  }
  public Orb(int x, int y, boolean d){
    orbx=x;
    orby=y;
    display=true;

  }
  public RectF drawOrb(){
    button.set(orbx, orby,orbx+30, orby+30);
    return button;
  }
}
```

So, why doesn't the android accept my Arraylist drawings? Thank you for your help.

Edit: So, I fixed my problem with button being null with the following code
 public RectF drawOrb(){

```
button.set(orbx, orby,orbx+30, orby+30);
if(button!=null)
return button;
else
    return b;
}
```

Now I receive multiple null pointer exceptions that look like this

```
[2011-04-23 22:31:25 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:574)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Thanks again

Comment: Could you please provide a stack trace of the error that terminates your application (you can use `adb logcat' to read the system log)?

Comment: I have no idea what to look for. Here is what it displayed
http://textbin.com/d3682

Comment: You are misreading your newly-edited output. That is not a stack trace from an error in your app. That is a stack trace from DDMS itself.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. But I still don't understand why button is null. It still says that button is null with these errors from the stack trace
E/AndroidRuntime(  872):        at com.djrobotfreak.Think_Fast.Orb.drawOrb(Orb.j
ava:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(  872):        at com.djrobotfreak.Think_Fast.TFView.onDraw(TFV
iew.java:130)

Comment: Those two lines happen to be {a} the button.set(button.set(orbx, orby,orbx+30, orby+30); and {b} canvas.drawOval(t.drawOrb(), p);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  312): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  312):        at com.djrobotfreak.Think_Fast.Orb.drawOrb(Orb.java:26)
```

You have a `NullPointerException` on line 26 of `Orb.java`. Based on your listings, that would appear to be:

```
button.set(orbx, orby,orbx+30, orby+30);
```

If so, `button` is null.

Comment: Well if that were true then this would fix it correct
public RectF drawOrb(){

 button.set(orbx, orby,orbx+30, orby+30);
 if(button!=null)
 return button;
 else
  return b;// b is another RectF that is set on creation.
}